# Access controller computed property from another controller

Tags: ember.js

I've got the following controller:

```
App.StudentIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    hasDebt: function(){
        var totalCredit = this.get('totalCredit');
        var totalCreditSpent = this.get('totalCreditSpent');

        if (totalCreditSpent > totalCredit) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }.property('payments.@each', 'lessons.@each'),

    availableCredit: function(){

        var totalCredit = this.get('totalCredit');
        var totalCreditSpent = this.get('totalCreditSpent');

        return totalCredit - totalCreditSpent;
    }.property('payments.@each', 'lessons.@each'),

    totalCredit: function(){
        var totalCredit = 0;

        var payments = this.get('payments');
        payments.forEach(function(payment){
            totalCredit += payment.get('amount');
        });

        return totalCredit;
    }.property('payments.@each', 'lessons.@each'),

    totalCreditSpent: function(){
        var totalCreditSpent = 0;
        var lessons = this.get('lessons');
        lessons.forEach(function(lesson){
            var duration = lesson.get('duration');
            var price;
            switch (duration)
            {
                case 45: price = 15; break;
                case 60: price = 20; break;
            }
            totalCreditSpent += price;
        });

        return totalCreditSpent;
    }.property('payments.@each', 'lessons.@each')
});
```

I need to access a few of these computed properties in the following controller to be able to calculate the totalDebt based on the debt of each student:

```
App.StudentsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    totalDebt: function(){
        var students = this.model.content;
        var totalDebt = 0;

        students.forEach(function(student){
            if (student.hasDebt)
            {
                totalDebt += student.availableCredit;
            }
        });

        return totalDebt;
    }.property('student.payments.@each', 'student.lessons.@each'),
});
```

However this doesn't work. I suppose it doesn't because the computed properties are in the controller, and I'm trying to access them from the model.

What's the best solution to access the computed properties in the `StudentIndexController` from `StudentsIndexController` controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your, ahem, needs go a little beyond the `needs` api since you want to access computed properties for *each* model and not just for one. Using the `needs` feature gives you access to the *singleton* controller of that name. If you get access to the one `StudentIndexController` instance, there's no telling what model (if any) inhabits that controller. You instead need to use the `itemController` api to wrap each of your students with a non-singleton instance of your student controller.

See this jsbin that solves your problem (with much simplified models). http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gexuj/2/edit

The gist is this: your array controller will define the `itemController` property to be the conventional name of the controller you want to wrap each model in context. Then, you can access those cool computed properties on each student and aggregate them as you desire.

```
App.StudentsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'studentIndex',
  doesAnybodyHaveDebt: function () {
    return !!this.filterBy('hasDebt').length;
  }.property('@each.hasDebt')
});
```

Look for more information on the item controller property here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is exactly what I was looking for. Can you please provide an example to show me how to run a forEach inside the `doesAnybodyHaveDebt` computed property to `console.log` each value?

Comment: I've updated the jsbin with that example. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gexuj/4/edit You're 90% there just from the way you phrased your question. Doing a `this.forEach(...);` inside the computed property on the `ArrayController` is the ticket. Remember that an `ArrayController` implements the `Ember.Enumerable` interface: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html

Comment: Great! The main issue is that I was using `this.model.content.forEach` instead of `this.forEach`. Thanks a lot for your help and for your example, it has been extremely helpful.

Comment: Ah yes, going straight to the model objects bypasses the cool item controller wrapping stuff. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 4):

Controllers can gain access to each other via the `needs` property (see [this entry in the EmberJS guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/))

The needs property is an array of controller names, and you can then access the controllers via the `controllers` property, as below.

```
var StudentsIndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['studentIndex'],
  totalDebt: Ember.computed('controllers.studentIndex.payments.@each', ....),
  ....
});
```

If that's a little verbose for you, you can always alias the controller.

```
var StudentsIndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
 needs: ['studentIndex'],
 student: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.studentIndex'),
 totalDebt: Ember.computed('student.payments.@each', ....),
 ....
});
```

Finally, if you prefer the syntax, you can also change the `needs` value to be a single string, like `needs: 'studentIndex'`

Comment: I understand the usage of `needs`, however I cannot understand the usage of the `Ember.computed` line: I need to access the property `hasDebt` in the `StudentIndexController`. Can I please ask you to update the example in your answer? Thanks

Comment: That's an alias, so you don't have to type the whole path every time, it creates a property that you can refer to as being the output of that path. So if you type, within the scope of this controller: `this.get('student')`, you're accessing the whole path to the controller you're injecting with `needs`. In this code I believe it should be `this.get('student.hasDebt')` or `var s = this.get('student'); s.get('hasDebt')`, I think